# Permalink with taxonomies in Zola

Tags: zola

I am trying to port my Jekyll site to Zola, but I can not figure out how to configure permalinks for posts/etc with taxonomy prefixes. With Jekyll, I had `/:category/:title` setting, but there seems to be no way to replicate this in Zola. Could one work around this limitation with aliases/something else?

Comment: Looks like its not possible at the moment